# Data Stax Cassandra - Auto provisioning and auto deployment cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have deployed 9 node datastax cassandra cluster (3 data centers) in google cloud.

Is there any way we can do the auto provisioning and auto deployment of VM's based on CPU Load?

Thanks,

Comment: Probably.  Have you checked out their documentation on auto-scaling?  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/

Comment: I understand how the auto scaling happens in Google Cloud. After generating VM how to add to the cluster automatically and how to remove from the cluster automatically after peak hours